# "Proper" vs "Appropriate" vs "Suitable"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, difference

As Cambridge Dictionary says, ["proper"](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/proper) means: "real, satisfactory, suitable, or correct". Also, it is said that, ["suitable"](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/suitable) means: "acceptable or right for someone or something". An finally, ["appropriate"](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/appropriate) means: "suitable or right for a particular situation or occasion".

As you see, they have lots of semantic overlaps which makes a person who lacks the requisite intuition fall into doubt when it comes to use each case. This is why I decided to provide you with some examples to discover how and when to use each case. I would appreciate it if you kindly let me know about the wrong choices for each case. Here are my examples:

> 1. Such movies are not ........... for children.

a. suitable 
b. appropriate 
c. proper

> 2. Two out of five people lack a .......... job in that country.

a. suitable 
b. appropriate 
c. proper

> 3. Such small studios are ............ for young couples who have no children.

a. suitable 
b. appropriate 
c. proper

> 4. I can't come to the ceremony tomorrow! I don't have any .............. clothes.

a. suitable 
b. appropriate 
c. proper

> 5. It is not a/an .............. time to ask her about this matter.

a. suitable 
b. appropriate 
c. proper

> 6. We will take .......... actions when it comes to.

a. suitable 
b. appropriate 
c. proper

> 7. They dont consider him a/an ............. husband for their daughter.

a. suitable 
b. appropriate 
c. proper

Please note that, to me as a non native, all choicea work for all cases above.

I have already visited the similar [thread](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14702/what-is-the-difference-between-appropriate-and-suitable) on the forum.

### Some useful links:

https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/fitting-suitable-appropiate-proper.2313993/

https://hinative.com/en-US/questions/3204687

https://www.englishforums.com/English/SuitableProperAppropriate/bbcnwp/post.htm

https://www.italki.com/question/191255

https://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/96774-what-is-difference-between-approperiate-and-proper

http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv108.shtml

https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-proper-apt-and-appropriate

Comment: Where do those sentences come from?

Comment: Most of them are taken from various contexts and dictionaries with some slight changes in order to clear off the possible ambiguities @Lambie.

Comment: Well, I see some red flags but in general think this type of question is much too broad.

Comment: You are right @Lambie, but I think that this is the only possible way to obtain a slight intuition about these types of synonymous words.

Answer (score 3):

The only one of the seven examples where I would use "proper" is

> 2. Two out of five people lack a proper job in that country.

For the others, your dictionary definitions state that "appropriate" applies to a "particular situation or occasion".

So I would use "suitable" in 1, 3, 4, and 7.

I would use "appropriate" in 5 and 6.

The anomaly is 4, and perhaps the usage is a matter of opinion too.

Comment: Thank you @Weather Vane, but I'm quite confident that for **#1** all choices would work (as I encountered many times in many occasions). Regarding **#2&3** I'm sure thay at least both 'proper' and 'suitable' work. Also, for #4 I have seen many cases including either 'appropriate' or 'suitable'.

Comment: As I wrote, some of the usage is a matter of opinion, and also depends on context such as whether the speaker is making a "value judgement", say when "proper" might be used by a speaker from one country, but not from another. As for #2 in the usual context, one talks about having a "proper job" (i.e. an *actual* job, with pay etc). As for #4, that's what I wrote so you don't disagree. In #3 "proper" would only be used by someone from a culture that has very strict traditions of what type of accomodation should be inhabited.